# defining arrays in schema when loading a JSON to bigquery table from bigquery WebUI

Tags: json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am loading a json file to a table in a  bigquery dataset . A sample json in that file is :

```
{"a": "string_a","b": "string_b","c": 4.42,"d_list":["x","y","z"]}
```

I define the schema field as:

```
a:string, b:string, c:float, d_list:string
```

This gives an import error  `Field:d_list, array specified for non-repeated field`

I think d_list should be defined as:

```
  {
    "type": "STRING",
    "name": "d_list",
    "mode": "repeated"
  }
```

Is it right? If yes how can I use WEbUI to define it in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Web UI also accepts JSON line as noted in the helper icon, so you can have a JSON array of fields defined as, and you can paste this into the web UI.

```
[
{
    "type": "STRING",
    "name": "a",
    "mode": "nullable"
},
{
    "type": "STRING",
    "name": "b",
    "mode": "nullable"
},
{
    "type": "FLOAT",
    "name": "c",
    "mode": "nullable"
},
{
    "type": "STRING",
    "name": "d_list",
    "mode": "repeated"
}
]
```

Comment: bigquery table has STRING,NUMERIC,RECORD,... but no ARRAY, possible to insert an array? i'm trying to move mongodb db to bigquery

Comment: @datdinhquoc Bigquery has ARRAY and STRUCT as well.

Comment: yeah, found them, RECORD type and REPEATED mode